Flutter Local Notification not seen on phone screen
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class LocalNotifications {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future<void> onDidReceiveNotification(
      NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {}

  static Future<void> init() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");

    const DarwinInitializationSettings iosInitalizationSettings =
        DarwinInitializationSettings();

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializationSettings,
      iOS: iosInitalizationSettings,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotification,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotification,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestNotificationsPermission();
  }

  static Future<void> showInstantNotification(String title, String body) async {
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails("channel_Id", "channel_Name",
          importance: Importance.high, priority: Priority.high),
      iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics);
  }

  static Future<void> scheduleNotification(
      String title, String body, DateTime scheduledData) async {
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails("channel_Id", "channel_Name",
          importance: Importance.high, priority: Priority.high),
      iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(0, title, body,
        tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledData, tz.local), platformChannelSpecifics,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }
}


This is my Local Notification
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/core/extensions/padding_ext.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/core/extensions/text_style.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/core/shared/presentation/components/buttons/app_button.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/core/shared/presentation/components/inputs/text_field.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/view/main/tasks/data/model/task_model.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/view/main/tasks/data/provider/task_provider.dart';

class CreateTask extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateTask({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateTask> createState() => _CreateTaskState();
}

class _CreateTaskState extends State<CreateTask> {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _dateController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _startTimeController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _endTimeController = TextEditingController();

  final FocusNode _dateFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _startTimeFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _endTimeFocusNode = FocusNode();

  String _selectedCategory = 'High';

  Future<void> _selectTime(BuildContext context,
      TextEditingController controller, FocusNode focusNode) async {
    final TimeOfDay? picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
    if (picked != null) {
      setState(() {
        controller.text = picked.format(context);
      });

      focusNode.requestFocus();
      focusNode.unfocus();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
    );
    if (picked != null) {
      setState(() {
        _dateController.text = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(picked);
      });
      _dateFocusNode.requestFocus();
      _dateFocusNode.unfocus();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nameController.dispose();
    _descriptionController.dispose();
    _dateController.dispose();
    _startTimeController.dispose();
    _endTimeController.dispose();
    _dateFocusNode.dispose();
    _startTimeFocusNode.dispose();
    _endTimeFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        scrolledUnderElevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Add Task",
          style: TextStyles.heading24.copyWith(
            fontSize: 22,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.h,
              ),
              AppTextField(
                controller: _nameController,
                label: 'Task name',
                hint: 'Working',
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12.h,
              ),
              AppTextField(
                controller: _descriptionController,
                label: 'Description',
                maxLine: 5,
                hint: 'I work today...',
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12.h,
              ),
              DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: _selectedCategory,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Select Category',
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 15.h,
                    horizontal: 20.w,
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF806DFB)),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF806DFB)),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
                items: ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']
                    .map((category) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: category,
                          child: Text(category),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedCategory = value!;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12.h,
              ),
              AppTextField(
                hint: 'Date',
                enabled: true,
                trailing: Icons.calendar_today,
                controller: _dateController,
                focusNode: _dateFocusNode,
                onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12.h,
              ),
              AppTextField(
                hint: 'Start time',
                enabled: true,
                trailing: Icons.access_time,
                controller: _startTimeController,
                focusNode: _startTimeFocusNode,
                onTap: () => _selectTime(
                    context, _startTimeController, _startTimeFocusNode),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12.h,
              ),
              AppTextField(
                hint: 'End time',
                enabled: true,
                trailing: Icons.access_time,
                controller: _endTimeController,
                focusNode: _endTimeFocusNode,
                onTap: () =>
                    _selectTime(context, _endTimeController, _endTimeFocusNode),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40.h,
              ),
              AppButton(
                color: const Color(0xFF806DFB),
                label: 'Save',
                onPressed: () async {
                  final task = Task(
                    name: _nameController.text,
                    description: _descriptionController.text,
                    category: _selectedCategory,
                    date: _dateController.text,
                    startTime: _startTimeController.text,
                    endTime: _endTimeController.text,
                  );

                  Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context, listen: false)
                      .addTask(task);

                  DateTime scheduledData =
                      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(seconds: 5));
                  LocalNotifications.scheduleNotification(
                      "Salam", "Necesen", scheduledData);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ).scaffoldPadding,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


This is my task page. When I create and Click button then need seen local notification.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/adapters.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:to_do_app/app/todo.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/model/todo_model.dart';
import 'package:userorient_flutter/userorient_flutter.dart';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await LocalNotifications.init();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  Hive.registerAdapter(TaskAdapter());

  await Hive.openBox('myToDoBox');

  UserOrient.configure(
    apiKey: 'b0841b71-e5b0-4b78-baa6-bd3b32815afb',
    languageCode: 'en',
  );

  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: ToDoApp(),
    ),
  );
}


This is main dart.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>


    <application
        android:label="to_do_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" android:exported="true"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


This is my manifest. But when I run app and create task then local notification not seen on phone ( I try it another phone also.
I try it anothor phone and emulator. Not seen local notification. I check it with youtube it seen a true without problem. But it not work

try running your app in debug mode and setting a breakpoint to find out where its going wrong

I try it. When debug, it write: notification successfully send
